# Javascript drag and drop - delay for allowdrop

Tags: javascript, drag

I'm currently stuck at the following problem:

I need to create a delay when dragover happens en then check if current dragover object is still the same. When it's the same object -> execute code.

This is my code:

```
var draggedId = null;
var triggered = false;

function allowDrop(ev) {

draggedId = ev.target.id;

setTimeout(function () {

    if (draggedId == ev.target.id && ev.target.id != "" && !triggered) {
        triggered = true;
        draggedId = "";
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

}, 2000);

}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave(ev) {

draggedId == "";
triggered = false;
}
```

Allowdrop function is the dragover event. 
ev.preventDefault() to allow the drop can't happen there because that function is assync.
Any idea's?

Thanks,

Mathias

Comment: Can you please give an example, like a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve and I can answer more fully ?

It's generally the case that you cannot always say for certain whether a drop will work, the best you can do is to setup drop zones on your page and have them cancel the dragover event based on what you can tell about the drop.  If you want to make your application work with cross window dragging, then you cannot rely on a global variable to store information about what is being dragged, and you cannot actually see what is inside the drag - you can only know what kind of thing is being dragged.  So if the drop might be acceptable you need to cancel the event.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234307/html-5-drag-and-drop-how-to-figure-out-whether-an-element-accepts-a-drop)

I think that maybe you are confused about how dragevents propagate which is the reason you think you need a timeout ?  But blocking the event queue to figure out whether you accept a drop, or trying to cancel the drag event after it has already bubbled to the top and been handled in the default way by the browser (which is to not accept the drop) isn't going to work.